# How do I pass the data from my View to the controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a concierge application where the user will register an entry and exit of vehicles, to register an entry I work with two tables, the user consults the associate by the license plate and checks if he is registered, yes I allow him to enter one of his another table, but I can't find a way to pass this data to the controller and insert it into the database, that is, how do I get the data from my `View`? And how do I enter the data in the database? follows my code from the View that is displaying the form and the Controller...

```
public ActionResult Buscar(string texto)
    {
        VeiculosDB vb = new VeiculosDB();

        var placa = vb.VEICULOGERAL.Where(p => p.PLACA == texto);
        return View(placa);
    }
```

In a way in my plate variable I have the data that is being displayed, but how would I do an insert with this data ?

```
@model IEnumerable<Portaria.Models.VEICULOGERAL>

@{ 
ViewBag.title = "Chegada";
}

<div class="panel-body">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Portarias", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="texto" placeholder="Placa..." />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default" name="texto" style="background-color:aliceblue" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TIPOVEICULO)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MARCA)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ANOMOD)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ANOFAB)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VEICULO)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COR)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UNIDADE)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ASSOCIADO)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODMARCA)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODVEICULO)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MATRICULA)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SITUACAO)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DATAINICIAL)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DATAFINAL)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.STATUSPRI)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESCSTATUSPRI)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.STATUSSEC)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESCSTATUSSEC)
        </th>
        <th hidden>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DATAORDEM)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TIPOVEICULO)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MARCA)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ANOMOD)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ANOFAB)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VEICULO)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COR)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UNIDADE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ASSOCIADO)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODMARCA)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODVEICULO)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MATRICULA)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SITUACAO)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATAINICIAL)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATAFINAL)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATUSPRI)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCSTATUSPRI)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATUSSEC)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCSTATUSSEC)
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATAORDEM)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: FormMethod.Post. No points to use form with GET

Comment: The form contains two inputs named "texto". So, it is a `string[]` instead of `string`.

Comment: This Get method is to get the information in the database according to the text typed and then display the View, but how do I get this data and insert it in the database the way I want? because here I'm trying to make the user's life easier, when he searches for the license plate and receives the driver's information, he can already insert it into a table in the bank without having to type the fields

Comment: @Alexander second name belongs to submit input. So I don't see 1st why to assign same name to this input. 2nd input make sense only for text in this case and hence it could be 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are using submit form mechanism with GET method. This isn't logical.

`GET === retrieve something from server`

`POST/PUT === send something to server`

So regarding your case just change

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Portarias", FormMethod.Get))
```

to

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Portarias", FormMethod.Post))
```

Since you're using this statement

`@model IEnumerable<Portaria.Models.VEICULOGERAL>`

your View will be populated based on the model's values above.

Comment: Correct, but this Get method is to get the information in the database and then display the View, but how do I get this data and insert it in the database the way I want? because here I'm trying to make the user's life easier, when he searches for the license plate and receives the driver's information, he can already insert it into a table in the bank without having to type the fields

Comment: Then you have to have 2 ActionResults. One without parameters (to render view ([HttpGet] attribute at top of the method) and one for send data ([HttpPost] attribute at the top of the method) with parameters)

Comment: Okay, I'll try to apply it here now

Comment: Okay, I need 2 buttons in the same View, one to fetch and one to send the data, how do I configure my controller to receive this data? my current code is like this

Comment: [HttpPost, ActionName("Buscar")]
        public ActionResult Inserir(string[] inserir)
        { 
            return View();
        }

Comment: I don't have a method yet because I'm just trying to get the data to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Split Buscar ActionResult to `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` methods.
With `[HttpGet]` you will retrieve data with controller from data to view.
with `[HttpPost]` action, you will retrieve data from view to database.

Firstly define your db object globally(outside from action methods):

```
VeiculosDB vb = new VeiculosDB();
```

In your view make your Form method "post" like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Portarias", FormMethod.Post))
```

inside the beginForm you can use a button with submit type like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

It will automatically send data to `[HttpPost]` action.

Your [HttpPost] Action can be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buscar(Vehicle v)
            {
                vb.Carname.Add(v); //vb from your global db object that I mentioned above.
                vb.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }
```

Comment: The problem is that I need this data for me to insert into the separate database, because if it were just to add to the table, this method would be enough, but I have other columns that I need to deal with